# How to query in SQL with those multi condition?

Tags: mysql

#### Table data(part)

`| user_id | count | create_time |
| ------- | ----- | ----------- |
| 10      | 20    | 2018-08-08  |
| 10      | 19    | 2018-08-09  |
| 2       | 15    | 2018-08-04  |
| 5       | 30    | 2018-08-10  |`

#### Query conditions

**Condition 1**: Query result must order_by `count` desc

**Condition 2**: `user_id` maybe repeat(for example: user_id=10)

**Condition 3**: Each `user_id` has only one piece of data after the query

**Condition 4**: The only one data from "condition 3" should be the one which `create_time` is most recent. In example, when `user_id=10`, the data's `create_time` should be "2018-08-09". (*this condition is optional*)

**Condition 5**: Limit 100

Comment: base on the table you've shown, what is your expected output ?

Comment: You tagged both mysql and Sql Server. Please edit your question tags to indicate which of the two database platforms you are using. Knowing the database platform will help in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conditions you specify, and the view of data you have given, this (MySQL) query should do what you want:

```
SELECT d.user_id, d.count
FROM data d
WHERE create_time = (SELECT MAX(create_time)
                     FROM data d1
                     WHERE d1.user_id = d.user_id)
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Output:

```
user_id     count
5           30
10          19
2           15
```

Condition 1 is satisfied by `ORDER BY count DESC`;
Conditions 2, 3 and 4 are satisifed by the subquery which selects only the value of `user_id` which has the most recent `create_time`;
Condition 5 is satisified by the `LIMIT 100`.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d5603/2)

For SQL Server, you can use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 d.user_id, d.count
FROM data d
WHERE create_time = (SELECT MAX(create_time)
                     FROM data d1
                     WHERE d1.user_id = d.user_id)
ORDER BY d.count DESC
```

The output is the same. [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8bab/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 100
   User_id,
   Count,
   (Select max(create_time) from table2 t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id)
   From table t
   Order by count desc
```